# Specify template directory in config

Tags: templating, config

Is there a way to specify a different template directory from the general config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in the config file, but you can from index.php using the [`CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/php-constants#craft-templates-path) constant:

```php
define('CRAFT_TEMPLATES_PATH', '../templates/');
```